# No puedo llamar al método de una instancia

Tags: php

Tengo definida la clase AuthenticationService cuyo constructor me devuelve ya un objeto user con el nombre matéo "según" yo, y lo que trato de hacer en mi método action de la clase control es crear una instancia de nombre $user que llama a mi clase AuthenticationService(devuelve un usuario mateo) y posteriormente imprimir en pantalla que Mateo esta bebiendo café..

Error del programa:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   AuthenticationService::drink() in
>   /Users/jeancarlostoaquezada/git/cursoPHP/poo/inyecciondependencias/index.php:17
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Users/jeancarlostoaquezada/git/cursoPHP/poo/inyecciondependencias/index.php(23):
>   control->action() #1 {main} thrown in
>   /Users/jeancarlostoaquezada/git/cursoPHP/poo/inyecciondependencias/index.php
>   on line 17

tengo 3 clases:

**user.php**

```
<?php

class user{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $properties;

    public function __construct($properties = array()){
        $this->properties = $properties;
    }

    public function __toString(){
    return $this->getName();
}
    public function getName(){
        if (isset($this->properties['name'])){
            return $this->properties['name'];
        }
        return 'Usuario';
    }

    public function drink($bebida){
        return $this->getName() . ' toma ' . $bebida;
    }

}
```

**coffee.php**

```
<?php
class coffee{
    public function __toString(){
    return 'Cafecito';
}
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require("user.php");
require("coffee.php");

class AuthenticationService{
    public function __construct()
    {
        return new user(['name'=>'Matéo']);
    }
}

class control{
    public function action(){

        $user = new AuthenticationService();
        $ceffe = new coffee();
        $mensaje = $user->drink($ceffe);
        echo "<h1>$mensaje</h1>";
    }
}

$persona = new control();
$persona->action();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres acceder a las propiedades de la clase "user" podrías añadir un getter en la clase AuthenticationService. El archivo **index.php** quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
require("user.php");
require("coffee.php");

class AuthenticationService{
    private $user;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = new user(['name'=>'Matéo']);
        return $this->user;
    }
    public function getUser(){
        return $this->user;
    }
}

class control{
    public function action(){

        $user = new AuthenticationService();
        $ceffe = new coffee();
        $mensaje = $user->getUser()->drink($ceffe);
        echo "<h1>$mensaje</h1>";
    }
}

$persona = new control();
$persona->action();
```

Answer (score 3):

El constructor de una clase nunca retorna un valor salvo la instancia de la clase en cuestión. Si estás intentando implementar algún tipo de modelo de tipo "Factory", lo adecuado es crear un método getUserInstance() (por ejemplo) dentro del la clase `AuthenticationService`, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
class AuthenticationService{
    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return user
     */
    public static function getUserInstance($name)
    {
        return new user(['name'=>$name]);
    }
}
```

Así puedes usarlo de esta manera:

```
<?php
$user = AuthenticationService::getUserInstance('Mateo');
$ceffe = new coffee();
$user->drink($ceffe);
```

Como consejo, según [los PHP PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#side-effects), un fichero que define una clase no debería hacer ninguna salida de datos (a esto se le llama side-effect), y viceversa, un fichero con side-effect, no debería declarar ningún tipo de clase. Es una buena práctica que deberías adoptar desde ya.

Comment: Desde PHP 5.4 sí se puede, con una salvedad sintáctica. `$name =( new AuthenticationService())->getName()`; Es la base de los frameworks con "fluent API" como Lemonade y Slim Framework.

Answer (score 1):

El mètodo `drink()` pertenece a la clase `user` no a `AuthenticationService` , realiza este cambio:

```
//$user = new AuthenticationService();
$user = new user();
$ceffe = new coffee();
$mensaje = $user->drink($ceffe);
echo "<h1>$mensaje</h1>";
```